# SQL Adjustment to query for selecting specfic times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query below to select points from a database. I need to make one slight adjustment, I only want points from '2013-09'. I have tried by simply adding AND "Time" LIKE '2013-09%' but that doesn't seem to work as it produces 0 records. I also know for a fact that the database contains records matching this year, as I have used the query below (with the time selection part removed) to select all the records . What might be the issue?

```
; WITH positions AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Message_ID
       , "Time"
       , Latitude
       , Longitude
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID IN (1, 3)
  AND    Latitude  > 45
  AND    Latitude  < 85
  AND    Longitude < -50
  AND    Longitude > -141
  AND "Time" LIKE '2013-09%' <- this is where I'd put it
)
, details AS (
  SELECT MMSI
       , Ship_Type
       , Vessel_Name
       , IMO
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY MMSI ORDER BY "Time" DESC) As row_num
  FROM   dbo.DecodedCSVMessages_Staging
  WHERE  Message_ID = 5
)
SELECT positions.MMSI
     , positions.Message_ID
     , positions."Time"
     , details.Ship_Type
     , details.Vessel_Name
     , details.IMO
     , positions.Latitude
     , positions.Longitude
FROM   positions
 INNER
  JOIN details
    ON details.MMSI    = positions.MMSI
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the records for previous month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use `LIKE`, change this line to:

```
AND [Time] > '2013-09-01'
```

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot.. In ArcGIS using the field calculator it makes you use like.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want values from September 2013 you can try this:

```
AND "Time" >= '2013-09-01'
AND "Time" < '2013-10-01'
```